# YOLOV3 object detection not detecting the object and bounding boxes are not bounding the objects

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, yolo, darknet

I am implementing YOLOv3 and have trained the model on my custom class ( which is tomato). I have used the darknet model 53 weights ( https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74) to start my training as per the instructions provided by many sites on training and object detection using YOLOv3 . I thought it was not necessary to list down the steps.

One of my object images used for training is shown below ( with bounding boxes using LabelImg):
[image]

The txt file for the above image  for the bounding boxes contains the following coordinates , as created using labellmg:

```
 0 0.152807 0.696655 0.300640 0.557093
 0 0.468728 0.705306 0.341862 0.539792
 0 0.819652 0.695213 0.337242 0.543829
 0 0.317164 0.271626 0.324449 0.501730
```

Now when I  use the same image for testing to determine the accuracy of detection, it is unable to detect all the tomatoes and moreover the bounding boxes are way off from the objects as shown below:
[image]

I am not sure what is going on.

I have cloned the git
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet and did a local make and trained the model on the custom object. Nothing fancy.
The pictures above were taken from my phone. I have trained the darknet using a combination of downloaded images and custom tomato pictures I had taken from my phone. I have 290 images for training.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model can't generalize well. Maybe your are training too much, which can cause over-fitting or even your dataset is small.

You can try testing on a never seen data (a new tomato picture) and sees if it does well.

Double-check your config files, if something is incorrect there, like you are using a yolov4 cfg in a yolov3 model.

And I recommend that you read this article in which can help you understand better how neural networks works:
https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-neural-networks-model-generalization-7baddf1c48ca

Comment: thanks for your comments. regarding testing on the never-seen-data, it seems to do pretty well - particularly on the web images. I am not using yolov4.conf  - but thanks for checking. The problem I have is with images I have taken. From what I am thinking ( currently testing it out - can't afford GCP GPU, so taking a break), the pictures I take with iphone seems to orients the images from landscape to portrait which makes the labelimg tool to mess it up. If my hunch is right, I will post the answer after testing it out